# Input Components Not Working

Tags: admin-on-rest

We are integrating AOR(version 1.2.3) with existing Application.
we are trying to provide Edit Feature in that when we give
<---Field> Components its working fine
also able to see SAVE button
but 
when it <---Input> Components
no SAVE button is visible and Component does take inputs.

Code when 
Field Components are used

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Components
} from 'admin-on-rest';
 
 const CustomerEdit = (props) => (
 <Edit {...this.props}>
         <TabbedForm>
           <FormTab label="Profile">
               <TextField source="firstName" />
               <TextField source="middleName" />
               <TextField source="lastName" />
           </FormTab>
           <FormTab label="Address">
           <ReferenceManyField addLabel={false} reference="CustomerAddresses" target="customerProfileId">
               <Datagrid>
               <EditButton/>
                 <TextField source="id" />
                 <TextField source="line1" />
                 <TextField source="pinCode" />
                </Datagrid>
             </ReferenceManyField>
           </FormTab>
            </TabbedForm>
     </Edit>
     );
     export default CustomerEdit;
```

Code when 
Input 
Components are used

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Components
} from 'admin-on-rest';
 
 const CustomerEdit = (props) => (
 <Edit {...this.props}>
         <TabbedForm>
           <FormTab label="Profile">
               <TextInput source="firstName" />
               <TextInput source="middleName" />
               <TextInput source="lastName" />
           </FormTab>
           <FormTab label="Address">
           <ReferenceManyField addLabel={false} reference="CustomerAddresses" target="customerProfileId">
               <Datagrid>
               <EditButton/>
                 <TextInput source="id" />
                 <TextInput source="line1" />
                 <TextInput source="pinCode" />
                </Datagrid>
             </ReferenceManyField>
           </FormTab>
            </TabbedForm>
     </Edit>
     );
     export default CustomerEdit;
```

This is App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// redux, react-router, redux-form, saga, and material-ui
// form the 'kernel' on which admin-on-rest runs
import { combineReducers, createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';


// prebuilt admin-on-rest features
import {
  adminReducer,
  localeReducer,
  crudSaga,
  TranslationProvider,
} from 'admin-on-rest';

import restClient from './restClient';
import GenericList from './ui/List';
import CustomerEdit from './ui/views/customer/customerEdit';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  admin: adminReducer([{ name: 'CustomerProfiles' },
  { name: 'CustomerAddresses' }]),
  locale: localeReducer(),
  form: formReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,
});
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const history = createHistory();

const store = createStore(reducer, undefined, compose(
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
));

sagaMiddleware.run(crudSaga(restClient));

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TranslationProvider messages={messages}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/profile"
              hasCreate render={
                (routeProps) => <GenericList resource="CustomerProfiles" {...routeProps} />
              } />
            <Route exact path="/profile/:id"
              hasEdit render={
                (routeProps) => <CustomerEdit resource="CustomerProfiles" {...routeProps} />
              } />
</Switch>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </TranslationProvider>
  </Provider>
);

export default App
```

This in case of Input Components
[No Data from Backend for CustomerAddress and also no Save Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8WUi.png)

This in Case of Field Component

[when we use <---FIELD/> Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CommP.png)

Comment: Aren't you missing the `CustomerAddresses` resource in the `adminReducer` ?

Comment: sorry i forgot put it there, but when even CustomerAddresses is there , output is not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have an error in the console about `ReferenceManyInput` ?  This component does not exist.

I checked the documentation and we indeed included it in the [Resources chapter](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Resource.html). It will be fixed soon.

For referencing many other resources, you should use the ReferenceArrayInput. However, it does not support Datagrids. There are not components allowing you to edit related resources yet.

Comment: sorry its ReferenceManyField only i forgot to mention...
my mistake
ReferenceManyField in <Edit/> works fine when Admin-on-rest practise project i made but when i tried to integrate its not working

Comment: You'll have to be more precise about "tried to integrate"

Comment: okay,
u see when i am following the documentation for Integration part(CustomApp.js) in the existing application its not working fine...

Comment: i hope u have  seen the screen shot!! i attached with question.

Comment: Ah I see now. Our documentation was not yet updated for the last version. It has been updated now. You are probably missing the following line `store.dispatch(declareResources([{ name: 'CustomerProfiles' }]));`

Comment: My pleasure! :)